# After OSX El Capitan upgrade resolution down

Tags: macos, mac, resolution, osx-el-capitan

I was happily using an external monitor (samsung s27d850) with my mid 2010 MBP with maximum resolution of 2560x1440. After upgrading to El Capitan there is no longer an option to pick this resolution for the above monitor, the max I am offered is 1080p, which is scaled and crap to look at :)

Is there any way to force OSX to work with an external monitor in El Capitan with 2560x1440?